# How to get chars/words/lines/blocks coordinates

Tags: text-extraction, pdftotext, poppler, pdf-scraping, xpdf

I'm doing pdftotext -bbox file.pdf and that produces word-level output.
Is there a way to output coordinates on the character/phrase/line/block level?

I'm interested in knowing if either the poppler or xpdf version of pdftotext can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use `pdftotext -bbox-layout` and it will give you the structure you need.

Comment: but even if the pdf has multiple pages 'pdftotext -bbox-layout' gives layout for 1st page only. any way to get it for all the pages?